# POST - Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm fairly new to angular and got stuck at getting data from SpringREST which is at backend.
So scenario is:I'll be getting a `JSON` string from backend as `POST`(JSON data will be redirected to my hosted link of site as POST) and I need to catch that JSON string and display it on UI.
I'm not sure about the `postMethod` in dataservice.ts if it should be there.

I googled on stackoverflow and came up with below code which doesn't seem to work in my scenario:

**Component.ts**

```
import { MyDataService } from './services/my-data.service';
constructor(private posting: MyDataService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.posting.postMethod().subscribe(
    (response => { 
      console.log(response)
    }));
}
}
```

**Data-service.ts**

```
@Injectable()

export class MyDataService {

  constructor(private http: Http)
  { }


 postMethod(model: any  ) {
    return this.http.post("http ://", model)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error in console ?

Comment: `.map(res => res.json());` shouldn't be needed

Comment: @baao It should be need IMO for v5 (if you are using `http` not `httpClient`)

Comment: `this.posting.postMethod()` pass your model here as argument.

Comment: @PardeepJain Ahh. Thanks you're right

Comment: `Http` is deprecated in angular v5. Use `HttpClient` instead

Comment: Yes your code seems right just need to pass model as param as per @Niladri

Comment: @baao NO, you can use `http` as well in v5

Comment: @PardeepJain You can use it, but you shouldn't use deprecated components. They will get removed completely in future releases, making your code unusable. Http is deprecated as of v5 and should not be used anymore. See https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-angular5/

Comment: @baao Agree !! as this is deprecate in v6

Comment: No, please read the article, or any angular changelog. It is deprecated since v5, since release 4.4 httpClient is shipped and should be used instead. @PardeepJain

Comment: Error is 'Cannot find name model'

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, You need to pass the parameter to the service when invoking

```
 this.posting.postMethod(model).subscribe(
    (response => { 
      console.log(response)
  }));
```

Comment: Error is 'Cannot find name model'

Comment: haha! that you need to know. i have mentioned what was the issue here

Answer (score 0):

As i can see in your component.ts you are not passing the model as a parameter.
 you  need to pass the model as a parameter.

```
  this.posting.postMethod(anyData).subscribe(
    (response => { 
      console.log(response)
    }));
```

If this is not the issue then please update us with the error you are getting.

Comment: Already posted so many answers stating same solution, why are you posting similar answers

Comment: Error is: Cannot find name 'model'.Although in postMethod,I've passed model.

Comment: I think we all have answered in parallel. @pardeep

Answer (score -1):

This is the right way to define a function in the subscribe method:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.posting.postMethod(model).subscribe(
    (response) => { 
      console.log(response)
    });
}
```

Comment: Not a downvoter but, Except param in the method, what is different way here?

Comment: response should be defined as an function, within the brackets (response), not directly.

Comment: NO, you can use it directly as well. It should work with/without brackets

Comment: It won't be considered as a function then.